# Term or phrase for simply moving a problem from one area to another

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to come up with (and coming up short) a term or expression that is used when one is simply moving a problem from one area to another (instead of solving it).

Something similar to;

> robbing Peter to pay Paul

... in the sense that it's a zero-sum game, but speaking more to moving issues instead to taking resources.

Comment: displacing or shifting a problem

Comment: In a software dev environment, I always referred to this as "sweeping it under a *different* carpet."

Comment: Look what I found for you: shifting the burden https://thesystemsthinker.com/shifting-the-burden-moving-beyond-a-reactive-orientation/ I cannot provide an answer because these guessing games are just that. Anyway....

Comment: @Lambie - I appreciate the engagement - "shifting the burden" seems to fit.  If you want to enter an answer w/ that I will accept it.

Comment: 'kicking the can down the road'

Comment: [Offload](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+offloading&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+offloading&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4675j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is commonly used this way.

Comment: "moving the problem from one area to another" is quite vague in the sense that it's not clear whether the action involves some sort of dispute. Is one department saying it's up to another department to solve?  Is a front-end developer saying it needs to be fixed in the back-end, or vice-versa? Is one political administration leaving it up to the next administration? Some phrases would be better suited to leaving the problem for someone else to solve and others would be better suited to a "turf battle".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a systems person who has written a piece and calls this "shifting the burden" in an organizational setting.

**SHIFTING THE BURDEN: MOVING BEYOND A REACTIVE ORIENTATION** [sic]

[shifting the burden](https://thesystemsthinker.com/shifting-the-burden-moving-beyond-a-reactive-orientation/)
aka displacing or shifting a problem from one thing to another

Comment: +1 I like it. "shifting the burden" sounds like moving some baggage from one side of the camel to another: it hasn't gone anywhere, and still has to be carried.

Comment: This is not an established expression...any other similar one would fit the bill. Not really helpful!!!

Comment: If that is the case than the question is just a POB issue.

Comment: @user240918 Completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

The phrase [passing the buck](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pass-the-buck) comes to mind.

It's when someone shifts a problem to someone else rather than solving it.

Which is also how the phrase [the buck stops here](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/the-buck-stops-here) was derived from.

Comment: passing the buck specifically refers to responsiblity.

Comment: @Lambie I assume you mean 'culpability'. But this answer is fine; CED has 'to leave a difficult problem for someone else to deal with' – the non-culpability sense of 'responsibility'. / There are enough duplicates to close-vote here, though. It's non-CVing that bothers me.

Answer (score 0):

***[sweep something under the carpet](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/sweep-something-under-the-carpet)*** (in British)
or rug

> - to conceal (something, esp a problem) in the hope that it will be overlooked by others

(Collins)

Comment: This is not British or American. It is just English.

Comment: That's not really it - not looking for concealment, but more shifting the problem to another person or area.

Comment: @Lambie - Collins defines the saying as British, but you are probably more informed than the Dictionary.

Comment: **To sweep something under the carpet or rug** means to disregard the thing.

Answer (score 0):

"Pushing bones around the graveyard" is the worst form of shifting a problem from one place to another -- it's aimless, it's acting like the bones will make a difference anyway, it's futile.

Answer (score 0):

**whack-a-mole** (countable and uncountable, plural whack-a-moles)

> (*idiomatic, chiefly Canada, US*) The practice of trying to stop
> problems, etc., that repeatedly occur in an apparently random manner;
> also, the act of dealing with such matters in a piecemeal manner
> without achieving a complete solution.
>
> *Trying to get rid of spam e-mails is like **whack-a-mole**: as
> soon as you delete one, another appears.*
> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whack-a-mole)

> Used with reference to a situation in which attempts to solve a
> problem are piecemeal or superficial, resulting only in temporary or
> minor improvement.
>
> *The site's security team has an ongoing battle against spammers, but it's a game of **whack-a-mole***
> [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=whack-a-mole%20definition)

---

> So as our minds wander, we use our precious consciousness to ponder
> real and imagined problems. But our frantic lives start to resemble a
> game of **Whack-a-Mole**, resolving one problem, only to see more crop up
> in other areas.
> [Joseph Metzger; *Is What We See...All We Get?*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vKTVCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&dq=whack-a-mole%20problems%20in%20other%20areas&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw9JTc5ZuDAxUPD1kFHZuVDUoQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=whack-a-mole%20problems%20in%20other%20areas&f=false)
> (2015)

> Church sees two main pathways to reverse aging. One is the silver
> bullet approach, to find a way to address again at a cellular level,
> which would help avoid the **"whack-a-mole" effect** of fixing one
> problem, only for another to quickly appear.
> [Peter Ward; *The Price
> of Immortality*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_sRNEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA180&dq=whack-a-mole%20problems%20in%20other%20areas&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw9JTc5ZuDAxUPD1kFHZuVDUoQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=whack-a-mole%20problems%20in%20other%20areas&f=false) (2022)

> **Getting Beyond Whack-a-Mole**
>
> Much of the conflict around school reform is plagued by a lack of a
> center, a common starting point. So it has become a game of
> **whack-a-mole**. You know, problems pop up around us and we take a whack at them: Common core—whack. Voucher—whack. Teacher unions—whack.
> Charter schools—whack. Poverty—whack. Special needs—whack.
> Funding—whack. Testing—whack. There is no end because there is no
> center.
> [Rex Miller et al.; *Humanizing the Education Machine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TgpPDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&dq=whack-a-mole%20problem&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyj7Sv55uDAxVOElkFHQSRAl0Q6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=whack-a-mole%20problem&f=false)
> (2016)